# Is the set of all singular matrices under standard operations a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question is very difficult for me to visualize.  It asks me to determine whether the below is a vector space and if not, what axiom it fails:

> The set of all $2\times2$ singular matrices with the standard operations

I would appreciate any hints to help me to understand what I need to do to identify a failed axiom.

Comment: hints: Is it possible to add two singular matrices and have a result that is non-singular? I think it is. So, the set of all 2x2 singular matricies is not a vector space. You just have to come up with a counter example along these lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

We have that: $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1\cr}$ are both singular matrices. What happens when you add them?

Comment: I get the identity matrix which is non-singular. Great point!

Comment: I feel like I don't know how to attack these problems without guidance.  Do you have suggestions how I can get better at this?  Should I just keep studying the axioms?

Comment: With Linear Algebra, the first step to doing these types of problems is understanding the definitions. Once you know your definitions, the next step is being able to understand what the problem is asking for? Is it true? Is it false? If true, prove it. Otherwise provide a counterexample. Honestly, knowing your definitions is key.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**.  First you would check to see if the zero matrix is in this set.  It is, because
$$\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&0\cr}$$
is singular.  Therefore this does not resolve the question.  Next you might check the "closure under addition" axiom.  This means that if you add any two singular matrices, you will always get a singular matrix.  However
$$\pmatrix{1&2\cr0&0\cr}$$
is a singular matrix, and if you use your imagination you may be able to find another singular matrix which, when added to this, gives a non-singular sum.